# Is there a way to update supplementary view efficiently, analogy to update items efficiently using reconfigureItems?

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS15, we have an efficient way to update items cell, by using `reconfigureItems`.

Here's the code snippet to perform such efficient update.

### Update items cell efficiently using `reconfigureItems`

```
private func reconfigureRecordingRow(_ recording: Recording) {
    var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
    snapshot.reconfigureItems([recording])
    dataSource.apply(snapshot)
}

private func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
    let dataSource = DataSource(
        collectionView: collectionView,
        cellProvider: { [weak self] (collectionView, indexPath, anyHashable) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            guard let self = self else { return nil }

            guard let recordingCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withReuseIdentifier: "recording",
                for: indexPath) as? RecordingCell else {
                return nil
            }
```

When `reconfigureRecordingRow` is called, cellProvider's function will be executed.

`collectionView.dequeueReusableCell` is able to re-use **existing** `UICollectionViewCell`, without constructing new `UICollectionViewCell`

---

However, I was wondering, how can I achieve a similar efficiency, if I have a section, with header supplementary view, and without any item? For instance

### Not able to update supplementary view efficiently

```
private func reloadAttachmentRow() {
    var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
    let sectionIdentifiers = snapshot.sectionIdentifiers
    if sectionIdentifiers.contains(.attachment) {
        snapshot.reloadSections([.attachment])
    } else {
        snapshot.insertSections([.attachment], beforeSection: .title)
    }
    dataSource.apply(snapshot)
}


dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] collectionView, kind, indexPath in
    guard let self = self else { return nil }
    
    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
        let section = indexPath.section

        let sectionIdentifier = self.sectionIdentifier(section)
        
        switch sectionIdentifier {
        case .attachment:
            guard let collageViewHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(
                ofKind: kind,
                withReuseIdentifier: "attachment",
                for: indexPath) as? CollageViewHeader else {
                
                return nil
            }
```

When `reloadSections` is called, `dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider` will be executed.

As per my testing, `collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView` will return a new instance of `UICollectionReusableView` each time.

As a result, I can visually observe the entire section is "flickering", when `reloadAttachmentRow` is called.

---

I was wondering, how can we update supplementary view efficiently?